# Как в Apache POI добавить картинку в XWPFRun?

Tags: java, изображения, apache-poi

Я нашел, [как добавлять](http://osdir.com/ml/dev-poi.apache.org/2011-04/msg00012.html) в документ картинку. Там сделано методом переопределения типа `XWPFDocument` - делается через xml-дескриптор...

В версии Apache POI 3.8-beta3 появилась возможность добавлять картинку в `XWPFRun` (который размещается в `XWPFParagraph`, который можно разместить в ячейке таблицы). Целью является добавление картинки не в документ, а в ячейку таблицы. Используя новый метод `XWPFRun`:

```
public XWPFPicture addPicture(InputStream pictureData, int pictureType, String filename, int width, int height)
```

Созданный документ не открывается, хотя его размер увеличился с учетом добавленной картинки. Word пишет: "Не удается открыть файл из-за проблем с его содержимым. Местоположение: Часть: `/word/document.xml`, Строка: 2, Столбец: 0". Как из вордовского doc файла извлечь этот `document.xml`, я так и не понял. В исходном коде `addPicture` для `XWPFRun` я заметил, что по сравнению с `addPicture` для `XWPFDocument` там присутствует код, похожий на [это](http://osdir.com/ml/dev-poi.apache.org/2011-04/msg00012.html) и даже есть небольшой xml-дескриптор внутри кода. Я пытался переопределить `XWPFRun` так само, как показано в [примере для `XWPFDocument`](http://osdir.com/ml/dev-poi.apache.org/2011-04/msg00012.html), но заменить xml-дескриптор на тот, что в примере. Но пока не получается, потому что вылетает ошибка в строке

```
classesHTMLtoDoc.CustomXWPFRun tmpRun = (classesHTMLtoDoc.CustomXWPFRun) tmpParagraph.createRun();
```

Описание ошибки:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun cannot be cast to classesHTMLtoDoc.CustomXWPFRun
  at servlets.getDocServlet.processRequest(getDocServlet.java:83)
  at servlets.getDocServlet.doGet(getDocServlet.java:134)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:216)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun cannot be cast to classesHTMLtoDoc.CustomXWPFRun
```

Неужели никто не добавлял никогда картинку в таблицу?